# DNS: a "short" query (UDP) does not return an address, but a "long" (ANY, TCP) query does

Tags: networking, systemd, dns, systemd-resolved

This is a companion to [an AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1139709/dns-problem-cannot-find-host-fixed-by-running-host-a-address-what-does-that) question I posted before I had learned enough to ask this question.

(This is for Ubuntu 18.04)

By watching the debug output from `systemd-resolved`, I can do queries like:

```
host foo.mycompany.com
```

and see that what's happening is that `systemd-resolved` is deferring to my local DNS server (in my router) with a UDP query.  That comes back with a response that convinces `systemd` to create a `NODATA` cache entry.

However, when I do:

```
host -a foo.mycompany.com
```

to request an `ANY` query, the debug output clearly indicates that the UDP response packet was truncated, so it falls back to a TCP query. When that returns, `systemd` apparently sees a valid address and creates a *positive* cache entry.

You can check the linked question, but the bottom line is that it makes some domain names only work (for a while) if I do a `host -a` lookup for the domain.

What I don't know is what it is that might be messed up that would cause this behavior. I don't think it has anything to do with `systemd-resolved` itself, because if I bypass that and go straight from my machine to the router DNS the results are the same (though I can't see the debug trace of course). I don't *think* my router is part of the problem, since a co-worker was able to see the same effect (and he's not in my house).

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if the difference might not be UDP vs TCP, but the query type ("A" vs "ANY")

Comment: Both probably. TCP serves longer answers and ANY brings more aditional glue to populate the DNS cache.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro we're starting to think it has to do with caching servers being reluctant to return "private" IP addresses. That kind-of makes sense, though it's not clear why they're willing to do so for `ANY` queries.

Comment: I would go for missing glue if talking about internal DNS servers.

Comment: I don't know what "missing glue" means.

Comment: Fair enough, my fault. https://ns1.com/blog/glue-records-and-dedicated-dns

Comment: Guess: Bug in error handling in systemd-resolved, or some other systemd part (no TCP fallback path for truncated UDP reply). Did you check the systemd source code?

Comment: @dirkt no I have not started diving into source code. I think we've concluded that it's a "problem" caused by intermediate caching DNS servers configured not to forward RFC1918 "private" IP address ranges. The `ANY` queries work because those aren't cached (generally).

Comment: So you don't receive a truncated UDP response, you receive no response at all?

Comment: @dirkt for simple queries, the local `systemd` server does get a response, but it's a negative response (basically "not found"), so the local server adds a `NODATA` record to its cache. With an `ANY` query, however, it does get a positive response with a good IP address. So the authoritative server is willing to return the `172.20` addresses, but intermediate caching servers (sometimes) are not.

Comment: @dirkt it's a security thing that I kind-of understand; it is intended to prevent those subnets from being hijacked by naughty people.

Answer (score 2):

I think that we've determined that what's happening is some intermediate caching servers (for example, the server in my home router) are reluctant to return RFC1918 ("private") addresses. Thus the short queries that most software does (browsers etc) will leverage those caches, but the server returns what amounts to a "not found". The local `systemd` server therefore caches a `NODATA` entry because it thinks that's the right thing to do.

An `ANY` query isn't cached by intermediate servers, so the local server gets a response from the authoritative server.

Or something like that. I'll leave the question unanswered for now in case somebody who actually knows how these things work can explain better.